# How to redirect the Page While Onclick Function when Click the Menu in asp using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, menu, repeater

My vb Code Bedind Like

```
   Private Function GetCategories() As DataTable

        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("KRGCbiz").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT MenuId,Menus FROM MenusDetails ", connection)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                dt.Load(reader)
            End If
            reader.Close()
        Catch generatedExceptionName As SqlException
            Throw
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
    Private Function GetAllCategories() As DataTable

        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("KRGCbiz").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand("select SubMenuId,SubMenu,MenuId,Menus from Submenus ", connection)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                dt.Load(reader)
            End If
            reader.Close()
        Catch generatedExceptionName As SqlException
            Throw
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function

Protected Sub rptCategories_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCategories.ItemDataBound
        If True Then
            If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
                If allCategories IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
                    Dim drv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
                    Dim ID As String = drv("MenuId").ToString()
                    Dim Menu As String = drv("Menus").ToString()
                    Dim rows As DataRow() = allCategories.[Select](Convert.ToString("MenuId=") & ID, "Menus")
                    If Menu = "Home" Then
                        //drv("Menus").Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Home();")
                    End If
                    If rows.Length > 0 Then

                        sb.Append("<ul>")
                        For Each item As DataRow In rows
                            sb.Append("<li><a href='#' >" + item("SubMenu") + "</a></li>")

                        Next
                        sb.Append("</ul>")
                        TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("ltrlSubMenu"), Literal).Text = sb.ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

My Aspx Page Like

```
   <asp:repeater ID="rptCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCategories_ItemDataBound">
                    <headertemplate>
                        <div class="menu"><ul>
                    </headertemplate>
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#'> <%#Eval("Menus")%></a>
                            <asp:literal ID="ltrlSubMenu" runat="server"></asp:literal>
                        </li>

                    </itemtemplate>
                <footertemplate>
                       </ul></div>
                </footertemplate>
                </asp:repeater>
```

I want to Redirect the Page when drv("Menus")="Home",, If i click the Menu Home Means i want to Redirect the Page, How to Do?
**My Java script Like**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function alertMe() {
        alert("License");
        window.location.replace('SoftwareLicenseDetails.aspx');
     return false;
}

  function Home() {
        alert("Home");
        window.location.replace('SystemDetails.aspx');
        return false ; 
}
  </script>
```

output Like

[image]

if click home Means want to Redirect another Page
How to Do?
I tried Last 4 days But i didn't Get Anything For My Requirement,
Help Me!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

try this `window.location.href = 'SystemDetails.aspx';`

Comment: Java script working but how to call java script from VB code behind?

Comment: `If Menu = "Home" Then
    //drv("Menus").Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Home();")
     End If` This line How to call java Script